# Running another function from DoGet in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google Apps Script. I have developed a script to change Google Calendar Event colors based on substrings in Calendar titles. A friend said they also wanted it. I tried to deploy the script as a Web app, so they could have a link to run it, and quickly found out that I need doGet or doPost. However, my script doesn't otherwise need those. I tried adding doGet(e) to my script, with the intent to call my main function from there, but I can't get that work. How do I turn my simple calendar-editing script into a web app? I see that most people have html landing pages, but is that required?

In the below example, when I run it, it completes execution right away. When I run it as Web App, I get this error: "The script completed but did not return anything". However, the function to color the events did not execute (the events did not get color-coded).

```
function doGet(e) { //I also tried just doGet()
  ColorEvents(); //I also tried ColorEvents and Call ColorEvents
}

function ColorEvents() {
  Logger.log("Color some events");
    var objDateToday = new Date();
   var objDateFuture = new Date();

  objDateFuture.setDate(objDateFuture.getDate() + 7);
  Logger.log(objDateToday + " " + objDateFuture);

  var objCalendarOwned = CalendarApp.getAllOwnedCalendars();
  Logger.log("found number of calendars: " + objCalendarOwned.length);

  for (var i=0; i<objCalendarOwned.length; i++) {
    var objCalendar = objCalendarOwned[i];
    var objEvents = objCalendar.getEvents(objDateToday, objDateFuture);
    for (var j=0; j<objEvents.length; j++) {
      var objEvent = objEvents[j];
      var strTitle = objEvent.getTitle();
      if (strTitle[0] == "%") {
        objEvent.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.MAUVE);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The long-term goal is to develop something that other people can trigger (e.g., daily look through the calendar for events to format), so this might not be the right path, but it would provide something in the interim.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].  We work better when we can see the script.  [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)  You will probably want to create an addon or perhaps a library

Comment: Not sure if you have this typo in your code, but in the one you provided, the brackets are missing when calling `ColorEvents()`. Without that, the function won't be called. Also, what makes you think that function did not execute? Can you provide the corresponding code?

Comment: yes the brackets. and you do need to return html or text, [read the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: Why don't you just give them a copy of the script to run from their account?

Comment: @JanineWhite, I'm pretty new to this, and I don't presently know how to do that. It looks like you can share projects to other accounts, is that what you mean?

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk I don't think that is true. I presently have it working jumping straight from the DoGet to my function.

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk If this is the function, they could go to whichever folder they want the script to be in, Click New>More>Google Apps Script,  copy and paste the function in, then run it from there. Or, Right click>Make a copy, then move the copy to a shared drive they have access to, so they can move or copy it wherever they want to use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the problem. In testing things out, I have different script files with the same function inside. I didn't realize that when you click the "run" button for a script, that it could potentially run the same function for a different script/file, and I think that is what happened. So, I made all of my functions in the script files in that project uniquely named, and I think it is working now. I'm surprised it would work like that, so keeping an open mind that something else was wrong.